# filter NSArray using (NSDate Predicate) until the whole Array is filtered

Tags: swift, nspredicate

i'm having difficulty for defining  my question in title so if my title is not appropriate then please do correct me ok so thing is that  i have an 
`NSArray` named  `results` which is fetched from `CoreData` and in this array the  items have `date` key which is of NSDate type   .  i want to predicate the `NSArray`  according to the months on `Date` key , and am able to do that manually this is how am doing this :

```
 let predicated = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@ AND date <= %@", start, End)
 var filtered =  results.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicated)
```

here `start` and `end` are `NSdate` which  are   first and last date of a given month  say am predicating something like "give me the results which are between  1 jan to 31 jan" and its working fine

but i want to predicate my whole `result` array in a way so that i don't have to provide the date range  ,  like a function which will take the `NSArray` and give me the output with variables of months like

```
func  filterResultArray(NSArray) -> name of months with results {

// here predicate the whole array and add them to the founded months variable 

}


print( "\(filterResultArray(resultsArray) )") // should print  :
jan = 5 , feb = 18 , march = 5 , may = 87
```

please tell me what am trying to do using this type of approach is even possible or not and if yes the please give me a little hint or direction about how am gonna do that it'll be so helpful for me

for better understanding please see the example:

```
example - myArray = [ "1,01,2016", "4,01,2016" ,"28,01,2016", "6,02,2016" "25,02,2016", "29,02,2016"  "4,03,2016", "4,04,2016"  "10,04,2016", "24,04,2016"  "9,05,2016", "29,05,2016"  "17,05,2016", "24,05,2016"  "12,06,2016", "13,06,2016"   ]
```

now how can i filter this array so that i can get a results something like :

```
January = 3
feb = 3
march = 1
april = 3
may = 4 
june = 2
```

Comment: create a new `NSCountedSet` and then for every item in results get date, from it get the month (`NSCalendar` operations) and put it into the set. In the end your counted set will contain exactly what you want.

Comment: @Sulthan thanks for responding man , okay let me try what you just said

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545518/how-to-count-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-swift-array in case you're interested in a solution that doesn't involve NSCountedSet.

Comment: @JoshuaKaden yeah your suggested link seems better option , but how am gonna count (with an range of months ) ?? in an NSArray ?

Comment: because in my array values are like   `["1,01,2016","21,01,2016","04,02,2016"]` they are not as similar as the answer's item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that @Joshua has shown you looks very elegant - assuming you are only interested in the month - meaning March 2016 counts as the same thing as March 2015 - then when you're parsing your data into `myArray`, just create an array of `myMonths` and strip out the middle data element to give you the month.

It's going to look something like this -

```
let dateComponents = resultDate.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
myMonths.append(dateComponents[1])
```

if you **do** need to include the year in the count, then just append the strings so that you get `"201603"` or `"032016"`