# Get each unique element in array and keep count for tableview swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to iterate over an array and find all the duplicates. I want to populate my TableView with ONE of each of the unique items in the array, and be able to use a segmented controller to sort by the name of the item OR the count of the item...

I want the cell to have labelOne = unique array object, and labelTwo = how many times that object is repeated.

For example

```
var exampleArr = ["apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "cat", "cat", "laptop"]
```

I want to be able to say **apple: 4, cat: 2, laptop: 1**

[I found this answer...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545518/how-to-count-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-swift-array)

My concern is that these answers (from hyperlink) return dictionaries.

Is it possible to create a sortable table view using a dictionary? Or is there a better way to do this

Comment: In the linked question there's an answer suggesting `NSCountedSet`. That is a possible solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSCountedSet` can do what you are looking for (requires `Foundation`)

```
let exampleArr = ["apple", "apple", "apple", "apple", "cat", "cat", "laptop"]
let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: exampleArr)
for item in countedSet {
    print(item, countedSet.count(for: item))
}
```

---

To use the set in a table view create an array from the unique objects

```
var dataArray = [String]()

dataArray = countedSet.allObjects as! [String]
```

You can even sort the array

```
dataArray.sort()
```

In `cellForRow` get the item from `dataArray` and the occurrences from `countedSet`

```
let item = dataArray[indexPath.row]
let occurrences = countedSet.count(for: item)
```

---

Note:

`NSCountedSet` has no idea about the type of the containing items, so if you need the type you have to cast it:

```
print(item as! String, countedSet.count(for: item))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have never used NSCountedSet. In the TableView numberOfRowsInSection I am trying to use countedSet.count but it seems to want count(for:) similar to what you described above. How can I return the Int that the method wants?