# What does Hash Values for Set Types in swift?

Tags: swift, hash, set

***when i read swift documentation i can not understand what that mean?.***
A type must be hashable in order to be stored in a set—that is, the type must provide a way to compute a hash value for itself. A hash value is an Int value that is the same for all objects that compare equally, such that if a == b, it follows that a.hashValue == b.hashValue.

Comment: This is because Set must have unique elements. That's the reason the type must be Hashable.

Answer (score 5):

`Set`s are designed for performance.  The `contains(_:)` method on `Set` is O(1) complexity meaning it takes a constant amount of time to perform no matter the size of the set.  `contains(_:)` on an `Array` is O(n) meaning the time to determine if the array contains an element increases as the size of the array increases.

How does a `Set` do that?  It uses a `hashValue` for the items of the `Set` and contains an internal dictionary like structure that maps the `hashValue` to the list of items with that `hashValue`.  This makes testing equality of complex structures (like `String`) very quick because `Set` first tests if two values have the same `hashValue`.  If the `hashValue`s are different, it doesn't need to check the contents of the `struct`s themselves.

To test if the `Set` `contains` a value, it is necessary to only look up the `hashValue` in the dictionary and then compare the item to the values that match.

So, for items to be contained in a `Set`, it is important to provide a hashing function that:

1. Is the same if two structs/objects are equal. (**absolute requirement**)
2. Computes a wide range of `hashValues` so that the items are widely distributed and don't require falling back to the slower check for equality. (**for good performance**)

---

Here is an example of a `Hashable` `struct` that is appropriate for storage in a `Set`:

```
struct Option: Hashable, CustomStringConvertible {
    var title: String
    var key: String
    var value: Int
    var description: String { return "{title: \"\(title)\", key: \"\(key)\", value: \(value)}" }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(title)
        hasher.combine(key)
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Option, rhs: Option) -> Bool {
        return lhs.title == rhs.title && lhs.key == rhs.key
    }
}
```

**Note:** In this example, only the `title` and `key` properties are considered for equality.  Two structs can be equal even if they have different `value` properties.  The `hash(into:)` function likewise only considers the `title` and `key` properties.